Table Decimal Alignment using siunitx package
Unable to center align the table data while using Decimal align option.
LaTeX Coding:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Table Decimal Align

\begin{table}[!h]
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|S[table-number-alignment = center]|S[table-number-alignment = center]|S[table-number-alignment = center]|S[table-number-alignment = center]|}
\hline
ESG  & 2088  & 21.658  & 6.811  & 9.091  & 44.628\\
DS  & 2088  & 23.698  & 2.166  & 17.279  & 28.391\\
GTI  & 2088  & 0.837  & 1.203  & 0  & 4.682\\
CSR  & 2088  & 1.569  & 1.309  & 0.599  & 6.795\\
IC  & 2088  & 35.208  & 7.571  & 13  & 50\\
SIZE  & 2088  & 23.018  & 1.276  & 20.361  & 26.191\\
LEV  & 2088  & 0.460  & 0.191  & 0.071  & 0.893\\
CR  & 2088  & 2.173  & 2.134  & 0.383  & 15.521\\
GROWTH  & 2088  & 0.143  & 0.301  & 0.398  & 0.833\\
ROA  & 2088  & 0.011  & 0.014  & 0.016  & 0.065\\
SHARE  & 2088  & 0.371  & 0.158  & 0.074  & 0.793\\
BOARD  & 2088  & 2.197  & 0.182  & 1.791  & 2.708\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
{}
\end{table}
\end{document}

OUTPUT:


It's not clear what you mean. But you should use table-format.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Table Decimal Align

\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{tabular}{
  |c|c|
  S[table-format=2.3]|
  S[table-format=1.3]|
  S[table-format=2.3]|
  S[table-format=2.3]|
}
\hline
ESG  & 2088  & 21.658  & 6.811  & 9.091  & 44.628\\
DS  & 2088  & 23.698  & 2.166  & 17.279  & 28.391\\
GTI  & 2088  & 0.837  & 1.203  & 0  & 4.682\\
CSR  & 2088  & 1.569  & 1.309  & 0.599  & 6.795\\
IC  & 2088  & 35.208  & 7.571  & 13  & 50\\
SIZE  & 2088  & 23.018  & 1.276  & 20.361  & 26.191\\
LEV  & 2088  & 0.460  & 0.191  & 0.071  & 0.893\\
CR  & 2088  & 2.173  & 2.134  & 0.383  & 15.521\\
GROWTH  & 2088  & 0.143  & 0.301  & 0.398  & 0.833\\
ROA  & 2088  & 0.011  & 0.014  & 0.016  & 0.065\\
SHARE  & 2088  & 0.371  & 0.158  & 0.074  & 0.793\\
BOARD  & 2088  & 2.197  & 0.182  & 1.791  & 2.708\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}

The braces around the tabular are useless, as is {} at the end. Also [!h] is a bad specifier: if the table doesn't fit in the page you'd like to be, it will block all subsequent tables and all of them will be printed at the end of the chapter.


The option table-number-alignment = center places the decimal marker -- here, . -- in the middle of the column. This is less than ideal here because the numbers don't have the same number of integer digits and decimal digits.
I therefore suggest you drop the option table-number-alignment = center from all four S-type columns and, instead, use table-format=x.3 options, where x (the number of integer digits) should be either 1 (the second S column) or 2 (the other three).
Do also consider getting rid of all vertical rules -- they won't be missed. In fact, omitting all vertical rules will immediately give the table a more open and inviting "look". Finally, I'd like to suggest that you left-align the contents of the first column.

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \bottomrule, and \addlinespace macros

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l 
                    c 
                    S[table-format=2.3]
                    S[table-format=1.3]
               *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]} @{}}
\toprule
ESG  & 2088  & 21.658  & 6.811  & 9.091  & 44.628\\
DS  & 2088  & 23.698  & 2.166  & 17.279  & 28.391\\
GTI  & 2088  & 0.837  & 1.203  & 0  & 4.682\\
CSR  & 2088  & 1.569  & 1.309  & 0.599  & 6.795\\
\addlinespace
IC  & 2088  & 35.208  & 7.571  & 13  & 50\\
SIZE  & 2088  & 23.018  & 1.276  & 20.361  & 26.191\\
LEV  & 2088  & 0.460  & 0.191  & 0.071  & 0.893\\
CR  & 2088  & 2.173  & 2.134  & 0.383  & 15.521\\
\addlinespace
GROWTH  & 2088  & 0.143  & 0.301  & 0.398  & 0.833\\
ROA  & 2088  & 0.011  & 0.014  & 0.016  & 0.065\\
SHARE  & 2088  & 0.371  & 0.158  & 0.074  & 0.793\\
BOARD  & 2088  & 2.197  & 0.182  & 1.791  & 2.708\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


@Zarko - Thanks! Fixed now.
